# List JSON names

Tags: javascript, json, key

I have the following JSON object

```
var json = [{
    "users" : [{
        "pete" : {
            "name" : {
                "first" : "Peter",
                "last" : "Parker"
            }
        },
        "dave" : {
            "name" : {
                "first" : "David",
                "last" : "Green"
            }
        }
    }]
}];
```

And I cant figure out in javascript, based on this JSON how to create an array of users that would contain pete and dave.

Comment: can you tell what do you want in answer?

Comment: I am looking for a function that would create array containing pete and dave from given json please

Comment: what is problem with `Object.keys(json[0].users[0])?

Answer (score 1):

`json` is an array containing an object, that object contains an array with two objects where the keys are the names, you can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get those names.

```
Object.keys(json[0].users[0])
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fD94V/)